# postgresql db in ubuntu

Tags: postgresql

how to install , create postqresql db and connect to the project in ubuntu

I cant do this
......................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
sudo -u postgres psql
[sudo] password for narjes: 
could not change directory to "/home/narjes/Documents/my_city/my_city": Permission denied
psql (14.9 (Ubuntu 14.9-0ubuntu0.22.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# createuser narjes
postgres-# createdb dbsh
postgres-# psql
postgres-# alter user narjes with encrypted password '123456';
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "createuser"
LINE 1: createuser narjes
        ^
postgres=# createuser narjes
postgres-#
```

Answer (score 1):

```
postgres=# createuser narjes
postgres-# createdb dbsh
postgres-# psql
postgres-# alter user narjes with encrypted password '123456';
```

The change from `=#` to `-#` indicates that you're contonuing the previosu SQL command/query in a new line.

Finish your sentences with `;`

Comment: This is  wrong: the first three commands run in the terminal, not the psql shell.

Comment: He is not running them on the terminal though.